# IE 7 expected identifier, string or number

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a problem and cant seem to find it for the life of me because my code works in all other browsers except IE7. This is the error im getting "expected identifier, string or number"

This is my code.

```
    function calculate() {
        var principal = document.loandata.principal.value;
        var interest = document.loandata.interest.value / 100 / 12;
        var payments = document.loandata.years.value * 12;

        var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, payments);
        var monthly = (principal*x*interest)/(x-1);

        if (!isNaN(monthly) && 
            (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
            (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {

            document.loandata.payment.value = round(monthly);
            document.loandata.total.value = round(monthly * payments);
            document.loandata.totalinterest.value = 
                round((monthly * payments) - principal);
        } else {
            document.loandata.payment.value = "";
            document.loandata.total.value = "";
            document.loandata.totalinterest.value = "";
        }
    }

    function round(x) {
      return Math.round(x*100)/100;
    }

    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#button').click(function(){
          $('#option2').animate({
         height: '365px', }, 500 );
  });
});
```

But the problem seem to be where I have my animate function which is...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#button').click(function(){
          $('#option2').animate({
         height: '365px', }, 500 );
  });
});
```

any help is greatly apprecaited.

Comment: Aren't your .animate object parameters incomplete? What is the height value animating to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IE is confused by the extra comma:

Change:

```
height: '365px', }, 500 );
```

To:

```
height: '365px' }, 500 );
```

Answer (score 4):

remove the comma after '365px'